# Spring MVC application getting hung on server start up

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to deploy my spring  + Hibernate application on JBOSS. while i am starting the server, server start is getting hung. Last entry in the start up log is -

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [myDatabaseURL]
```

In my application there are around 80 hibernate mapping file. when I am removing all of them excluding one simple basic mapping file, application is able to connect to the DB.

I also try to connect to DB using PLSQL developer and I was able to connect. So in other words DB is working fine.

Any suggestion or pointer for debug ? What can be possible reasons which i am overlooking?

Thanks

Comment: Paste the complete log.

Comment: Decrease logging threshold in your log configuration.

Comment: Just to be sure, `myDatabaseURL` is accessible from the machine where JBoss server is?

Comment: @WeareBorg : can't do. it will be security violation for me.

Comment: Well, we cant exactly help you without reading some log or where it is going wrong, atleast relevant log is necessary. If you cannot post it, then you might as well ask developers from your company. Thoda log chalta he.. :D

Comment: @PredragMaric : server is running on local only and i am able to connect to DB from my local